# Android long-during TCP socket connection failure after some time

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

i'm writing a client-server application which uses TCP socket connection. In my android project, Service creates a thread for listening the TCP socket.

Everything seems OK. But i have got one problem.. My network service running in background fine; But some time later (10-15 min..), when i try to open my application (main activity) again, I can't get responses from the socket connection. It freezes or something?? i cant send or get TCP messages from the socket.. What can be the reason of this? I'm working on my phone, via 3G connection.

(Besides, the app running in the emulator hasn't got such this problem; I assume Its connection is stable, long-during )

Thank you for your answering.

Comment: Define "can't get responses from the socket connection". Do you mean when reading? and define "It freezes or something". What exactly happens? Nothing? Exception?

Comment: No exception.. I solved the question by sending keeping alive packets..

Answer (score 1):

Due to power optimizations and perhaps changes in connectivity (GPRS/HSDPA/Wifi) it's very likely your connection is being dropped.

In order to maintain a connection, your background service needs to claim a wakelock using the PowerManager class. This prevents the device from going to power-saving mode and thus disconnecting your socket. But beware, this significantly lowers the battery life of the device.

Also, you need to handle changes in connectivity which break your open connection. Android sends out a broadcast message named **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** to notify of changes in connectivity.

Depending on your use-case I would poll with when the device is in the sleep-mode and only build a connection when the device is actively in use or just use C2DM push notifications

Comment: Hmm, Thank you for your answering. Is Sending Keep alive packets every 3min or something can be the solution of mine? What do you think?

Comment: I suppose you could do that in combination with a wakelock, but you might still end up reconnecting every 3 minutes. Can you be more specific on where you need this for? A chat, push notifications?

Comment: yes it can be chat notifications.. But important point is, when i re open my application, the establishment of connection dont be supplied. connection lost somehow. I have to force stop my app. It is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I have experienced something like this in my apps, it has usually been because of power optimisations on the phone (which cant be overridden). If the socket has been idle for too long, it is automatically closed and needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending data from time to time? Like implementing a heartbeat protocol ? if you are not, you should...or maybe it has to do with socket READ/WRITE TIMEOUT

Comment: hmm I dont send any data time to time, should i send keep alive packets every 3min or something?.